# Microsoft HDInsight Dashboard service unavailable

Tags: hadoop, port, azure-hdinsight

When i try to open HDInsight Dashboard Services, it say "Service Unavailable HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable". The localhost port # is 8085.

Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the identity of the HadoopAppPool... see [this post on Microsoft](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/hdinsight/thread/e55dc1b8-5022-433f-8904-37b6f1a7877a).